# How do I hide date in Google snippet using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to hide the date in my Google snippet and I currently use Yoast
SEO plugin. I couldn't change there so I thought I could change it
myself. I notice you have the 'the_date' function in 9 matches across
7 files. However, I thought I can use Javascript instead of PHP.

```
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
```

I can replace with,

```
<script language="javascript"
type="text/javascript">document.write("<?php the_time('F jS, Y')
?>");</script>
```

Google does not use javascript when pulling data for the description.
So it will display for the user but not read by Google.

I could do these in the free themes but am unable to find the required function. I am not sure what to replace with what.

In my files, I can only see,

```
C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\cover.php:
   52  // Day
   53  if( is_day() ){
   54:  $title = get_the_date();
   55   $title_above = __('Daily Archives', 'brook');
   56  }
   ..
   58  // Month
   59  if( is_month() ){
   60:  $title = get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'brook' ) );
   61   $title_above = __('Monthly Archives', 'brook');
   62  }
   ..
   64  // Year
   65  if( is_year() ){
   66:  $title = get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'brook' ) );
   67   $title_above = __('Yearly Archives', 'brook');
   68  }

C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\infobar.php:
   29               <div class="meta--items fl">
   30                   <div class="meta--item meta--date">
   31:                      <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
   32                   </div>
   33               </div>

C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\loop_item-grid_gallery.php:
   84               <div class="meta--items">
   85                   <div class="meta--item meta--date">
   86:                      <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
   87                   </div>
   88  

C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\loop_item-list_archive.php:
   66  
   67               <div class="meta--item meta--date">
   68:                  <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
   69               </div>
   70  

C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\loop_item-widget_list.php:
   19  
   20           <div class="meta--item meta--date">
   21:              <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
   22           </div>
   23  

C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\post_meta.php:
    2  
    3   <div class="meta--item meta--date">
    4:      <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
    5   </div>
    6  

C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\TheDefensionem\related_posts.php:
   59  
   60               <div class="meta--item meta--date">
   61:                  <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
   62               </div>
   63  

9 matches across 7 files
```

What do I do about it?

Comment: It's not celar what you want to do... do you want to show the date or not?

Comment: you cannot use javascript to write php code, the page has already gone through the php parser and left the server when your javascript code executes

Comment: Hide the date Julio. I see, so how do I hide the date in the Google snippet? Any other way?

Comment: removed "Please do help. Will be much appreciated. Thank you."

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want google to use certain data on your webpage then detect googlebot (the crawler google uses to obtain snippets) and do not display the information

```
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != "GoogleBot"):?>
   <div class="meta--items fl">
      <div class="meta--item meta--date">
         <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
      </div>
   </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Replace *GoogleBot* with whatever [useragent google uses](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) for their bot

This would require you to edit the themes files, so these changes may get overwritten on an update.